What are the exactly eigenvalues of the ARPACK zneupd function return?
I want to solve the eigenvalue problem (EVP): $Ax=\omega Bx$, and use the znaupd function from ARPACK and zneupd to extract the eigenvalues and eigen vectors. Here I use the shift-inversed mode that $(A-\sigma B)^{-1}Bx=\lambda x$ (i.e. iparam(7)=3 and bmat='G'). So, the original eigenvalues are $\omega=(1/\lambda) + \sigma$. I want to know, whether the values of $\omega$ have been recovered by the function zneupd or just this function returns the values of $\lambda$? Do I need to recover $\omega$ manually after getting the results from zneupd?
Furthermore, if I want to find the Largest Real or Imaginary part of $\omega$, and set which='LR' or 'LI', will the functions znaupd and zneupd return these values of $\omega$ under the "shift-inversed" mode? Or just return the largest real or imaginary parts of $\lambda$? Because under the shift-inverse mode, maybe the largest real parts of $\omega$  donot correspond to the largest real parts of $\lambda$.

Suggestion - take a small problem. Solve it with ARPACK. Also solve it with LAPACK. Compare the results. You should be able to answer all your questions then.

Thanks for @Ian Bush's suggestion. I have tried a simple EVP, and confirmed that ARPACK will return the original eigen values $\omega$, not $\lambda$.
